# What do I get "unused argument"?

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a function to a matrix, but I get that I have "unused arguments" in 
apply function. I do not know what I have to add to make the apply function work. It says
that I need to define n, y or z value, which are in `little.fun`. Without going into much detail this is the function of question:

```
MyFun = function (a,b) {

  mm=t(matrix(a,ncol=b-1))

  apply(mm, FUN=little.fun, MARGIN=1)  

  return(mm) 
}
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The function in question:

```
little.fun <- function(x,n) {  

  if (x==1) return(0) 
  y <- c(0,1)

  while (length(y) < x)     
  {
  position <- length(y)
  new <- y[position] + y[position-1]
  y <- c(y,new)  } 

  if(length(seq(n))>length(seq(y)))   
  {
    z = (rep(y,x,length.out=n)) 
  }else{  
    tail(y,n)
  }
   if((!tail(y,1) %in% tail(z,1))) warning("Recycling is not full!") 
  return(z) 
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `n` or `k` in the apply or set them as defaults in `little.fun`.  This would be easier to help you if it was reproducible (that is we could run your code and see what you see), but you don't provide `little.fun` or data to run `MyFun`.

Comment: How do I set them as defaults?

Comment: As I said earlier giving all the information will enable us to help you better.  Using words to do what could be done through demonstration is much less efficient.  Please provide all the code to minimally reproduce this.  This link discusses a MWE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  This will get you better answers faster.

Comment: @TylerRinker

I made my edit with the function!

Comment: Nice, can you post the data you tried to feed to `MyFun` now.  Or the `head` of it?  Also not sure what `n` is but if you supplied it here: `apply(mm, FUN=little.fun, n=SOMETHING, MARGIN=1)`, this would likely work.

Comment: @TylerRinker
The data for MyFun is `a=c(10,20,30)` and `b = 4`.

This function is basically a Fibonacci sequence generator that is recycling and prints a warning if the recycling is not full. I want it to use it on matrix. You can put (5,20) in the `little.fun` to see if it works.

Comment: What is `n`?  How do you calculate that?

Comment: I put n in the `little.fun` Its just an argument.

Comment: I get that but it's empty and you need to fill it with something.  Where does `n` come from?  Is it the `length` of something?  Is it a number you picked?  I ask because it needs to be passed to `little.fun` in the `apply` statement.  If the user supplies it then it should be an argument to `MyFun`.  If it is calculated from the data somehow then it should be calculated and then passed.

Comment: Well, n is length of the Fibbonaci seq. and I pick that number.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you closer but there are other issues.  You never assign to `z` in the `little.function` line:  `tail(y,n)`.

```
little.fun <- function(x,n) {  

  if (x==1) return(0) 
  y <- c(0,1)

  while (length(y) < x)     
  {
  position <- length(y)
  new <- y[position] + y[position-1]
  y <- c(y,new)  } 

  if(length(seq(n))>length(seq(y)))   
  {
    z = (rep(y,x,length.out=n)) 
  }else{  
    z <- tail(y,n)
  }
   if((!tail(y,1) %in% tail(z,1))) warning("Recycling is not full!") 
  return(z) 
}

MyFun = function (a, b, n) {

  mm=t(matrix(a,ncol=b-1))

  mm <- apply(mm, FUN=little.fun, n=n, MARGIN=1)  

  return(mm) 
}



MyFun(a=c(10,20,30), b = 4, n=4)

##      [,1] [,2]   [,3]
## [1,]    8  987 121393
## [2,]   13 1597 196418
## [3,]   21 2584 317811
## [4,]   34 4181 514229
```

Comment: Well, z is a vector that is created by the function.

Comment: @Trik23 Look at your function and think about what I said.  The function **does not** create `z` in the `else` part of your `if` {} else {}`.  You also do not assign `apply(mm, FUN=little.fun, MARGIN=1)` to anything so this is not what is returned.